# Как передать динамичный параметр через unit systemd для выполнения в bash скрипт

Tags: linux, bash, systemd

Нужно при выполнении unit файла myunit@param передать поле param ip-адрес или адрес домена для пинга.
то что у меня сейчас есть

```
`[Unit]
Description=Ping any domen or ip-address
After=network.target
After=sshd.service

[Service]
Type=forking
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/user/scripts/ping
StandardOutput=file:/var/log/ping.log
StandardError=file:/var/log/ping_error.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`
И сам скрипт который будет пинговать с переданым параметром param

```
#/bin/bash
sudo ping -c param
```

Не могу найти информацию как работать с параметром который будет изменятся и как его передать в скрипт

Comment: По-моему systemd не очень предназначен для передачи параметров, лучше запишите их в какой-нибудь файл и в своём скрипте читайте этот файл

Comment: Если вы всё-таки хотите передавать параметр вида `myunit@example.com`, то, во-первых, unit-файл должен иметь имя с собачкой `myunit@.service`, а во-вторых, в нужном вам месте подставьте `%I` что-то вроде `/bin/bash /home/user/scripts/ping %I`

Comment: Да, спасибо, ваша подсказка помогла. Про, то что файл должен быть с собачкой я знал, а вот как передать параметр после собачки не мог понять